# What most efficient method to find a that triangle which contains the given point?

Tags: c#, math

Given the triangle with vertices (a,b,c):

```
        c

      /   \

    /       \

  /           \

 a  -  -  -  -  b
```

Which is then subdivided into four triangles by halving each of the edges:

```
              c

            /    \

          /        \

     ca /            \ bc
           _   _   _
      /\              /\

    /    \          /    \

  /        \      /        \

a  -  -  -  - ab  -  -   -   -b
```

Which results in four triangles (a, ab, ca), (b, bc, ab), (c, ca, bc), (ab, bc, ca).

Now given a point p. How do I determine in which triangle p lies, given that p is within the outer triangle (a, b, c)?

Currently I intend to use ab as the origin. Check whether it is to the left of right of the line "ca - ab" using the perp of "ca - ab" and checking the sign against the dot product of "ab - a" and the perp vector and the vector "p - ab". If it is the same or the dot product is zero then it must be in (a, ab, ca)... Continue with this procedure with the other outer triangles (b, ba, ab) & (c, ca, ba). In the end if it didn't match with these it must be contained within the inner triangle (ab, bc, ca).

Is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT**

Here is a little more info of the intended application of the algorithm:

I'm using this as a subdivision mask to generate a fine mesh over which I intend to interpolate. Each of the triangles will be subdivided similarly up to a specified depth. I want to determine the triangle (at the maximum depth) within which the point p lies. With this I can evaluate a function at the point p using interpolation over the triangle. There is a class of triangles which is right-angled and they do comprise a significant portion, but they're much easier to work with and this algorithm isn't intended for them.

Comment: Markup doesn't make it easy to write questions based on ascii art ;-)

Comment: This is for sure a solved problem in computational geometry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location

Comment: @Christo -- you can put your ascii art inside <pre> </pre> tags

Comment: @Christo: You mean Mark*down*.

Comment: Is your large triangle always oriented such that the base is horizontal?

Comment: @Christo: I suggest you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264024/in-a-triangulated-isometric-grid-what-triangle-is-a-given-point-in/2264771#2264771. I say this based on your edit of the question. I don't think the current accepted answer is optimal (at least for the EDIT) and we can do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Triangles illustration]

- If the point is above ca/bc (i.e. in the top grey triangle) it's easy.
- If the point is left of ca (i.e. in the left grey triangle) it's easy.
- If the point is right of bc (i.e. in the right grey triangle) it's easy.
- If the point is in the middle, all you have to do is determine if the point is above or below the black V.

  You can do that by calulcating the y value of the line for the x value of the point and compare the result to the y value of the point.

  ```
  if (y' > (y * x') / x)
  {
      // center triangle
  }
  else
  {
      // right triangle
  }
  ```

Is this the most efficient method? I don't know.

Comment: Youre assuming this is a equilateral triangle that is aligned orthogonally in the coordinate system (points `a` and `b` have the same y value). The OP didnt make any of these assumptions...

Comment: I have to admit that I was primarily looking at the fancy ASCII art triangles instead of reading the surrounding text in detail :)

Comment: However you could apply a transformation to all points before that. That may be cheaper than the OPs original algorithm, especially if one applies that algorithm iteratively to isolate the point in triangles getting smaller and smaller. That would only cost one transformation for several applications of your method (that has far better performance).

Comment: Thanks, I think I can make it efficient. I expect it to be more efficient than the scheme I thought of initially.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an equilateral triangle? If so, then:

Let's say the height of your triangle is H.
Use the distance formula to compute the distance from c to p. If d(c,p) < H/2, p is in the top triangle.
If d(a,p) < H/2, p is in the left triangle.
If d(b,p) < H/2, p is in the right triangle.

If none of the above are true, p is in the center triangle.

If your triangle isn't equilateral, then disregard my answer.

Comment: The distance between *c* and *ca* is greater than H/2, but *ca* is in *c-ca-bc*. So this won't work.