# How to create isometric grid android

Tags: android, isometric

i want to draw i grid like

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160328125659/http://mathforum.org/workshops/sum98/participants/sanders/isomgrid.gif)

can some one please help me to create this grid programmatically in android

i am new to android game development and this is required for project

requirement is to create grid of tiles

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have already checked these places but i didnt find the exact answer

1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264024/in-a-triangulated-isometric-grid-what-triangle-is-a-given-point-in

2) http://www.gamedev.net/topic/445320-isometric-tile-coordinates/

3) http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016981/efficiently-getting-isometric-grid-positions-within-a-bounding-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to draw this you self. If seems doable. But if you dont know how drawing is done, these [tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2) should help.

Just use a combination of drawRect and drawLine to get this drawn.

Comment: i have already seen this tutorial but i did not found it useful
what i need to do is i need to draw a grid then in that grid i need to draw hero i.e. small boxes on random places

please help me by giving some links to good android isometric views